Title bar uses different theme color on Mac Catalyst than status bar
When a macOS Catalyst app is displayed on Mac computer the title bar (top most part of the window) is using a different theme than the status bar of the app (light instead of dark theme):

How do I change that to use the same theme as the rest of the app?
